# Transform Column value to header pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas DataFrame in the below format

```
|Header|Text   |
|------|-------|
|  AB  |yale   |
|  BC  |grass  |
|  BC  |window |
|  AB  |school |
|  BC  |student|
```

My expectation is to convert that DataFrame into the below format

```
|  AB  | BC    |
|------|-------|
| yale | grass |
| yale | window|
|school|student|
```

Until now I can't seem to find a way to get the expected format. kindly need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for new column for first column with compare `AB` in `Header` column with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and replace non matched values of `Text` to misisng values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with forward filling them, then reove rows if same values in `Text` and `AB` column by compare for not equal in [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and filter only columns specified in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'AB',  df['Text'].where(df['Header'].eq('AB')).ffill())
df = df.loc[df['Text'].ne(df['AB']), ['AB','Text']].rename(columns={'Text':'BC'})

print (df)
       AB       BC
1    yale    grass
2    yale   window
4  school  student
```